# Instagram OAuth Authentication - www.instagram.com redirected you too many times

Tags: oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to use the server side explicit OAuth flow to allow a user authenticate with Instagram, so my application can retrieve media on their behalf.

I have configured my client on Instagram, which is in Sandbox mode, to redirect to

```
https://localhost:44320/Admin/Instagram/OAuth
```

I am redirecting the user to Instagram using this URL:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID_IS_HERE&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44320%2FAdmin%2FInstagram%2FOAuth%3FweddingId%3D2&response_type=code&scope=public_content
```

My problem is that if the user is already authenticated, or successfully authenticates on Instagram, the redirect to my callback URL does not reach my endpoint and Chrome throws the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error. It also happens on Microsoft Edge browser but it just hangs rather than giving an error.

From inspecting the network activity on Chrome, there is bouncing back and forth from:

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=...
```

to

```
https://www.instagram.com/integrity/checkpoint/?next=/oauth/authorize
```

and then back again. I can't find any information on the Developer documentation and here on S/O from people experiencing the same thing.
I'd appreciate any help or suggestions as I'm stuck here!

Comment: What happens if you take out `/weddingId=2/` from the URL?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried it there and still the same. The instagram documentation says you can use additional parameters

Comment: What does `https://localhost:44320/Admin/Instagram/OAuth` do?

Comment: It's my callback url which accepts the code from Instagram and then Posts it back to them to retrieve the access token. It is not being reached by Instagram though.

Comment: Perhaps you can try clearing your browsers' cookies but since both Chrome and IE are getting the issue, I doubt that is a fix. It could also be the date and time on your server not matching the Instagram's server time zone?

Comment: @JohnMc were able to find a solution for this?  I am also hitting this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I gave up on Instagram entirely after they changed their API. I couldn't even log an issue with them!

Comment: Note regarding this issue; we have a customer running into it even though our own accounts are not having any issue. Just before posting this comment, I took the URL that safari was saying was redirecting infinitely (the integrity/checkpoint URL) and put it, copied character per character, in my own browser, and it worked. Whatever is going on, it must be related to user account settings or something.

Comment: I have this same issue @MikeFairhurst, and I can get it to work great in any browser, however not on a mobile browser (chrome or otherwise). Definitely not an account setting. I've tried on multiple accounts, all with the same error. I have not figured out a solution as of yet.